# How do I make VBA forcefully not save and close the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

When my worksheet opens I read a few lines from a local txt file, and display a UserForm with the contents gathered from reading the file. When my user clicks [image] on the userform, I want it to close the current workbook (just the current workbook, not the other ones which are opened)...

I tried using the following code in my UserForm called `activation` (code below) but it tends to close all the open workbooks instead of the current one it's supposed to close -

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

My ThisWorkbook Module has the following code in it -

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef dwflags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Public Function GetInternetConnectedState() As Boolean
  GetInternetConnectedState = InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&)
End Function
'---------------------------------
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Dim epath As String

epath = Environ("AppData") & "\3CD-MRL Utility\mrlconfig.txt"

Dim data As String
Dim hf As Integer: hf = FreeFile

If FSO.FileExists(epath) Then
    'do nothing
Else
    While GetInternetConnectedState = False
        MsgBox "Internet not Connected"
    Wend

    activation.Show
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, the code first checks if the .txt file exists or not. If it does, do nothing & if it doesn't, check if internet is connected and show the userform. The reason I am showing this code is when I click [image] on the `activation` form, before closing it asks to save/dont save my workbook - but technically my code above is not making any changes - so why does it ask? What should I do to not save the file and close it directly (only that file)? I'm grateful for any advice. Thanks! :)

Comment: [ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) to close a workbook without saving. Also possible is to set the [.Saved property to False](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saved) before closing.